# flex swf app - looking for unload() or onClosing() exiting() function

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I upload my flex client-side swf app to some website that loads different swf's on it's site. So you see your application floating in that website. My app is Flex swf app and has onCreationComplete() that starts the flow of logic. Now I want to do cleanup state and save state in a shared object when the application unloads (or probably exiting event, or closing event..) So do we have any function that I can implement and the flash platform automatically calls that function when the swf is unloading/closing/exiting?? (just like the onCreationComplet() function)

some thing like onUnloading(), or onUnload() or onClosing()...

Thanks

Comment: Hey Rose, how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an event listener to your main (root) object and have your method execute on [Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#REMOVED_FROM_STAGE) or add the listener to root.loaderInfo and execute on [Event.UNLOAD](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#UNLOAD).